# The sql delete query is successful but the data still remain

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete a record form the database using php, as I said in the title the sql delete query is successful but the data still remain. It directs me to hajj.php anyway, please help.

```
mysqli_query($connection,$sSQL) ;
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $query1=mysqli_query($connection, "delete from hajj where id='$id'");

    if($query1) {
        header('location: hajj.php');
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ist two lines part of code???

Comment: as the 2 answers so far mentioned remove '' arounf the $id. Plus always escape inputs that can be manipulated by the user (use at least mysqli_escape_string())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is that you use "'" in you're id. Since the database use an integer and not a string, then you don't use "'". Try to edit the query to:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM hajj WHERE id=$id");
```

That should do the trick.

Also, I see that you get the ID from the url $_GET['id'] please keep in mind that the code then will be SQL inject able. You should use mysqli_real_escape_string to prevent that (read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Example:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET['id']);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The id setting in where clause is not correct, you need to properly concatenate the $id variable like so :

```
$query1=mysqli_query($connection, "delete from hajj where id='".$id."'");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to concatenate the $id like this :

```
"delete from hajj where id=".$id
```

explenation: when writing "string with '$id' with single quotes" :

the '$id' is interpreted as a string since its inside a " ".

However, writing: "string with ".$id:

will evaluate $id and then concatenate the result with the string